# guava source code in IDEA has errors ,what 's happen

Tags: java, intellij-idea, guava

I want to study guava .so i want to build from source code 
1:git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/
2:import to IDEA
3:then Absent class  has error 
**the error is Class Absent must either be declared abstract  or implements abstract method 
transform(Function) in Optional** 

the more info ,see attach file 
how to solve it ?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Can you specify what kind of error is it? 2. Make sure your language level is Java 1.6

Comment: @Tomasz ,yes it is  java 1.6

Comment: it 's the Absent must be implements abstract menthod in Optional.

Comment: It doesn't matter... it shows in my libraries also. But i can still use it.

Comment: I don't think IDE just shows red line, could you find out the error message or hint in your IDE?

Comment: @Shengyuan Lu the Absent must be implements abstract menthod in Optional,you can try

Comment: @fuyou001 my eclipse works fine...

Comment: @Cemo File->New project ->Import project from external modlel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract class Optional has the following function:

```
public abstract <V> Optional<V> transform(Function<? super T, V> function);
```

The class Absent implements it like this:

```
@Override public <V> Optional<V> transform(Function<Object, V> function) {
```

This is correct Java. I think Idea has a bug here, when it does not recognize this overriding correctly. However you should be able to compile this code, because for compiling Idea uses the javac compiler.